# Read a file at resolved path in Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I have a node module and I want to make it compatible with webpack. I'm currently using the following pattern:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const someTemplate = require.resolve('./templates/template.css');

fs.readFile(someTemplate, 'utf8', (err, templateStr) => {
  // Do something with`templateStr`
});
```

The problem is that `require.resolve` will return the module id (number) instead of a path and of course doing a readFile operation on a number is going to fail.

How do I make it compatible with both node and Webpack.

Comment: what do you mean by make it compatible with webpack?

Comment: Are you encountering a specific issue? A description of what exactly you mean by "compatible with both node and webpack" as well as the details of any errors or issues you are encountering would be necessary to answer this question.

Comment: The problem is that `require.resolve` will return the module id (number) instead of a path and of course doing a readFile operation on a number is going to fail. So the code will not work in Webpack.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had to dig deep to find this one.

It seems it can be solved by using some browserify plugins along with webpack.

The answer below is a copy-paste since SO does not allow links-only answers

Say you have the following Node source:

```
var test = require('fs').readFileSync('./test.txt', 'utf8');
```

After `npm install transform-loader brfs --save`, add the following loader to your config:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./index.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "transform?brfs"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here's your link: https://github.com/webpack/transform-loader#typical-brfs-example

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I was looking for a way to do this without adding loaders. It doesn't have to be the same pattern that I've used in my original question.

Perhaps the best thing to do is just export the `template.css` as a string in `template.css.js`.

Comment: The `transform-loader` plugin hasn't been updated in 2 years, and this method doesn't seem to work any more - I get the following error when I try:
`SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`

Comment: There is a reason why SO doesn't accept links only answer, you've just hit it. The link is dead (invalid anchor not documented anymore)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is outdated and doesn't work anymore (the name of the loader has changed and there is issues with babel), this is an update to make it work

First run `npm install transform-loader brfs --save-dev`

You will need to add a file `brfs.js` in the same directory than your webpack config

`brfs.js`

```js
const brfs = require('brfs');

module.exports = function ModuleBrfs(resource) {
    return brfs(resource, {
        parserOpts: {
            sourceType: 'module'
        }
    })
};
```

And modify your webpack config with the transform-loader
`webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    //...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'transform-loader?'+path.resolve('brfs.js')
                    },
                    // The transform loader must be before all other loaders
                    // so if you need babel, add it after this line
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack bundles js code for frontend usage. Browser does not have `fs` module, and it can't do `readFile`. You can convert `template.css` to valid js and `require` it with webpack, or use some webpack `loader` to do such conversion on-the-fly.

Comment: Webpack bundles code for a lot of things besides just "frontend usage". It is widely used for serverless deployment, for example

Comment: This question is tagged node.js not browser, it is also in the description that he is building a node module